# JSON from TypeScript and JSON.stringify

Tags: json, typescript

Given this simplified scenario:

```
export class LoginComponent{ 
   grant_type: string="password"; 
   jsonPayload: string; 

   Login(username, password){
      this.jsonPayload = JSON.stringify(username, password, this.grant_type);
   }
}
```

It looks like stringify is confused by TypeScript's "this".  So, how do I make well-formed JSON, here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`stringify`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json.stringify) accepts three arguments, which are:

- The thing to stringify
- The replacer function to use
- The indentation to use

You're passing it a non-function (`password`) as the second argument.

You probably mean to pass it one argument, an object to `stringify`:

```
this.jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
    username,
    password, 
    grant_type: this.grant_type
});
```

or if you want to be explicit with all three since the last one needs it:

```
this.jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
    username: username,
    password: password, 
    grant_type: this.grant_type
});
```

Comment: Thanks, T.J.!  I've got well-formed JSON, now.  Only need to fix a niggling preflight bug...